# How to handle XML with same descendant names?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an unfortunate issue where the names of the root element and descendant element are the same, the second one has more descendents with info. Example below:

```
<dispatchnames>
    <dispatchnames>
        <first>mike</first>
        <last>allison</last>
    </dispatchnames>
    <dispatchnames> 
        <first>jeff</first>
        <last>ellington</last>
    </dispatchnames>
</dispatchnames>
```

I am attempting to code in C#, this is my current code for XML without the same name:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
IEnumerable<TrackData> data = from info in xdoc.Descendants("dispatchnames")
                              select new TrackData(
                                  info.Element("first").Value,
                                  info.Element("last").Value);
```

How should I handle it?

Comment: Good that you showed your attempted code in C#. How well does that code work? In what way does it fail?

Comment: Thanks :), i am getting a NullreferenceException - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I assume the error was because `info.Element("first")` returned a null reference, when `info` was the root node; so `info.Element("first").Value` was trying to extract `null.Value`. A good way to track down such problems is to test your intermediate results before dereferencing them: `first = info.Element("first"); if (first) select first.Value; else print "no <first> element";` (pseudocode)

Comment: correct, i was getting null.values, advice noted, thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `where` clause to verify that that element isn't the root element. If that element isn't actually the root, check `info.Element("first") != null` instead

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
IEnumerable<TrackData> data = from info in xdoc.Descendants("dispatchnames")
                              where xdoc.Root != info
                              select new TrackData(
                                          info.Element("first").Value,
                                          info.Element("last").Value);
```

Also, note that the XML you posted isn't well-formed. I tested this with XML structured as follows:

```
<dispatchnames>
    <dispatchnames>
        <first>mike</first>
        <last>allison</last>
    </dispatchnames>
    <dispatchnames> 
        <first>jeff</first>
        <last>ellington</last>
    </dispatchnames>
</dispatchnames>
```

Comment: thanks, the XML you wrote is the correct one. Your solution works perfectly!